# how to change button text using static function?

Tags: .net

I need to change a button text using an static function.

```
static string[] ARRay = new string[10];
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    for (int i = 1; i != args.Length; ++i)
    {
        command(i.ToString());
        ARRay[0] = i.ToString(); 
    }
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

static void command(string line)
{
    button1.Text = ARRay[0]; // here error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `button1` seems to be the member of the `Form Form1`. You need to first store the `Form1` instance in the `Main` method by first declaring a `static` member:

```
static Form1 myForm;
```

and then creating and passing that instance to `Run` method of `Application`:

```
myForm = new Form1();
Application.Run(myForm);
```

After you do this, you will have two options:
1. If `button1` is a `public` `Button`, you can use this line in your `command` method:

```
myForm.button1.Text = ARRay[0];
```

Or 2. You can declare a `public` method in `Form1` `class` to update the `button1.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the text of a button before it exists.

You have to start the application first, or at least create the form that it will use, then you can get a reference to the button and store it in a static variable, where you can reach it from a static method.

Answer (score 0):

Is button1 static? it should be to use it in a static method. check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28VS.80%29.aspx) for details.